# how to generate menu list from php arrray

Tags: php

I have a php array as following:

```
array(4) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(3) "151"
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "Beauty"
  ["href"]=>
  string(70) "http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151"
  ["menu_level"]=>
  int(1)
}


array(4) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(3) "160"
  ["name"]=>
  string(37) "   -Beauty Accessories"
  ["href"]=>
  string(74) "http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_160"
  ["menu_level"]=>
  int(2)
}

array(4) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(3) "154"
  ["name"]=>
  string(28) "   -Body Care"
  ["href"]=>
  string(74) "http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_154"
  ["menu_level"]=>
  int(2)
}


array(4) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(3) "155"
  ["name"]=>
  string(29) "   -Fragrances"
  ["href"]=>
  string(74) "http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_155"
  ["menu_level"]=>
  int(2)
}

array(4) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(3) "156"
  ["name"]=>
  string(44) "      -For Her"
  ["href"]=>
  string(78) "http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_155_156"
  ["menu_level"]=>
  int(3)
}

array(4) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(3) "157"
  ["name"]=>
  string(44) "      -For Him"
  ["href"]=>
  string(78) "http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_155_157"
  ["menu_level"]=>
  int(3)
}

array(4) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(3) "153"
  ["name"]=>
  string(28) "   -Hair Care"
  ["href"]=>
  string(74) "http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_153"
  ["menu_level"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

How can I generate multiple level menu based on the menu_level value of each array element.
I need a `<ul><li>` menu structure.

I want to produce something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>First Level</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>First Level</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Second Level</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Third Level</a></li>
                    <li><a>Third Level</a></li>
                    <li><a>Third Level</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Fourth Level</a></li>
                            <li><a>Fourth Level</a></li>
                            <li><a>Fourth Level</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
                                    <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
                                    <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>First Level</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Looks like a `for` or a `foreach` loop would do the trick.  What have you tried already?

Comment: i stuck on the closing of the ul and li for the when reach 2nd or 3rd  level.in future it could have more level.

Comment: Wanna post that code snippet?

Comment: i really stuck..all array elements are at first level/ one dimension. the only way to distinguish the menu level is the menu_level value

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here is **recursion**. In your data, it is currently flat. You need to first, properly structure the array and determine who's child is it. Ex: Inside fragrances, the are for men and women, so it means they are the child. It must be that way first.

After that structure of array is complete, then you need a recursive function to traverse that array and then from there build the list. Consider this example:

```
// dummy data (original flat array)
$raw_data = array(
    array(
        'category_id' => '151',
        'name' => 'Beauty',
        'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151',
        'menu_level' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => '160',
        'name' => 'Beauty Accessories',
        'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_160',
        'menu_level' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => '154',
        'name' => 'Body Care',
        'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_154',
        'menu_level' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => '155',
        'name' => 'Fragrances',
        'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_155',
        'menu_level' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => '156',
        'name' => 'For Her',
        'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_155_156',
        'menu_level' => 3,
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => '157',
        'name' => 'For Him',
        'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_155_157',
        'menu_level' => 3,
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => '153',
        'name' => 'Hair Care',
        'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=151_153',
        'menu_level' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => '152',
        'name' => 'Cloth Care',
        'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=152',
        'menu_level' => 1,
    ),

);

// this function fixes the structure, putting children on their proper parents
function recurse_structure($data) {
    $formatted_data = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {

        // check if this current iteration is a parent or child, check thru path string
        $id = parse_url($value['href'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($id, $href);
        $id = explode('_', $href['path']);

        // if its nested create a indexed path
        if(count($id) > 1) {
            $index = '['.implode('][', $id).']'; // create an array assignment
            $evaluate_string = '$formatted_data' . $index.' = $value;'; // build eval string
            eval($evaluate_string);
        } else {
            // just a normal parent
            $formatted_data[$value['category_id']] = $value;
        }

    }

    return $formatted_data;
}

$formatted_data = recurse_structure($raw_data); // feed the raw data into the formatting

// this method make the list
function build_list($data) {
    $list = (is_array($data)) ? "<ul>" : "";
    foreach($data as $attr => $item) {
        if(is_array($item) || is_object($item)) {
            $list .= build_list($item);
        } else {
            if($attr == "name") {
                $list .= "<li><a href=$data[href]>$item</a></li>";
            }
        }
    }

    $list .= (is_array($data)) ? "</ul>" : "";

    return $list;
}

$list = build_list($formatted_data); // feed the build_list function with formatted

print_r($list); // final output
```